# Save html file in completely source code

Tags: html, curl, wget

I want get to some parameter in this web page:https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/16678118#section=2D-Structure ,

For example if I want to find the value of "Topological Polar Surface Area"

If I manually save the page with Internet Explorer then I can find the value with these commands

```
cat file.html | grep -c  "Topological Polar Surface Area" ,
```

However, if I want to save with commands `wget` or `curl` then I can't find the value.

Comment: You get what the server sends. If additional content is loaded afterwards via JS/AJAX, then of course you don’t get that. In this case, things get more complicated; “headless browser” is your search keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by an asynchronous load of the content via JavaScript. When you save a document via `wget` or `curl`, you won't get the content which was loaded dynamically from the web site, because JS won't be executed.

The data your are looking for is loaded from this JSON URL `https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/index/compound/16678118/JSON/`.

You can view the network tab in the chrome developer tools (or any similar) to see, which data is loaded from which URL.

Comment: I want the value of Topological Polar Surface Area (77.4 A^2) , in this JSON URL https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/index/compound/16678118/JSON/ I can find the value (77.4 A^2)

Comment: This is not a website where we do all the work for you. I explained why you don't get the expected result and and how you can solve it. Please investigate any further by yourself. I'll give you a hint: It's the other JSON URL which contains the values.